# Linq query contains two adjacent selects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that has been changed over time.

The current version grabs a bunch of rows (which can be duplicated), groups them by `PageId`, then Orders them on `Volume` and selects the first item in each group. The grouped result is output to a new class.

The query has ended up with two adjacent Select statements. It feels 'wrong', but I've tried every which way to combine the two Select statements, specifically trying to embed the second `.Select()` into `.First()` - is it possible or is what I've got as concise as it gets?

Here's one of the errors I get when I try to make changes:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the elements in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.
```

Query.

```
var result = Base.View.Query<Keyword>(query, inc => inc.Page)
.GroupBy(g => g.PageId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume).First())
    .Select(r => new LinkDTO(
        r.Term.ToLower().HighlightExcept(reservedWords),
        currentUrl.ToAbsolute(r.Page.Path)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to combine the select in just 1

```
var result = Base.View.Query<Keyword>(query, inc => inc.Page)
.GroupBy(g => g.PageId)
    .Select(g => new LinkDTO(
        g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume).First().Term.ToLower().HighlightExcept(reservedWords),
        currentUrl.ToAbsolute(g.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume).First().Page.Path))
```

Now is this more readable than the first one? I would disagree.

Comment: No, I definitely agree - the solution is not as elegant as I expected.